# Javascript module pattern with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an exercise which i don´t really understand, so I hope for some help for this.

I should hardcode a simple array and the exercise tells me this:

> Often, when we create our web applications, we have the need for test data. Implement a reusable nodejs module, using JavaScripts module pattern, which can provide random test data as sketched below:

```
var data = dataGenerator.getData(100,"fname, lname, street, city, zip");
```

This should return a JavaScript array (not JSON) with 100 test data on the form:

```
[{fname: "Bo", lname:"Hansen", street: "Lyngbyvej 26", city: "Lyngby", zip: "2800"},..]
```

If you call it like this:

```
var data = dataGenerator.getData(25,fname, lname);
```

it should return 25 test data as sketched below:

```
[{fname: "Bo", lname:"Hansen"},..]
```

I have some code here, but this dosen´t work yet:

```
  var dataGenerator = (function () {
var data = [
    {
        fname : "Bo",
        lname : "Bosen",
        ...
    },
    {
        fname : "jashkjh",
        lname : "jhsdkfj",
        ...
    },
    ...
];

return {getData : function (count, fields) {
    var result = [];
    var i = 0;
    var field;
    var j;


    fields = fields.split(/\s*,\s*/);


    while (i < count && i < data.length) {

        result.push({});

        // Det objekt vi arbejder på lige nu er i result[i]
        for (j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {

            result[i][fields[j]] = data[i][fields[j]];
        }

        i++;
    }       

    return result;
}};
})();

module.exports = dataGenerator;
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is usually a poor place to ask for help with homework assignments.  If you did want help, however, you should explain what you know, what you tried and what you don't understand.

Comment: I agree, but now i don´t expect that people write all the code for me, but can give a little hint in the right direction.

Comment: So what is the roadblock for you? How to write a node.js module? How to implement the dataGenerator itself? Please show some effort first.

Comment: Agree with @pawel.  Say exactly what parts you don't understand.  [Imagine you are us trying to answer this.](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)  Right now we have no idea what hint to give you.

Comment: BTW I'd answer the question with "a solution should be available on npm, why do you want me to reinvent the wheel?" So maybe have a look at [faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) source code on GitHub and try to either build on top of it or re-implement a basic version.

Comment: Just added some code. The thing i don´t understand is how to generate the arrays and get the 25 out or for example 50 of the generated test array like this. var data = dataGenerator.getData(25,fname, lname);

Comment: Whoever posed this problem (your teacher?) doesn't really know what they're talking about, IMHO. All node modules are re-usable, it's not like you could really write one that wasn't. Also, what is usually referred to as the "module pattern" is essentially a browser concept. In node, each **file** is a module. You would not export a "module" object containing methods such as `getData`, you'd just add it to the list of exports.

Comment: @torazaburo: What would you call a module that just executes some code but does not export anything?

Comment: I would generate the data on the fly instead of hardcoding an array tu pull from, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/w0haqpdL/

Comment: @Bergi, well if it does something useful, it can be "re-used" by anyone that cares to require it for the side-effects of running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the data body, but could try:

```js
var data=[{fname:"Bo",lname:"Bosen",street:"Lyngbyvej 26",city:"Lyngby",zip:"2800"},{fname:"jashkjh",lname:"jhsdkfj",street:"Fmsn 9",city:"Pra",zip:"1600"},{fname:"eeee",lname:"aaaa",street:"Eda 5",city:"Pre",zip:"3500"}];

var dataGenerator = {
 getData: function(count, fieldsStr){
  var result = [], fields = fieldsStr.split(/\s*,\s*/), i = 0;

  while(i < count && data[i]){
   var item = {};

   fields.forEach(function(key){
    item[key] = data[i][key]
   });

   result.push(item);

   i++
  }
  return result
 }
}

var results = dataGenerator.getData(2,"fname, zip");
document.write(JSON.stringify(results))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, now i can play a little around with it. Appreciate it!